# Need help with DTFT problem

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, frequency-domain

Prepping for exam and this is one of the practice problems: [image]

I just want some clarification on some of the steps my professor took. This is the answer in the answer sheet [image]

Only thing I dont understand is how the domain of Y is determined. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what the domain of $X$ is ? Just take that and shift it by $\pm \pi/4$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it comes from the Fourier transform of $x[n]$. Once you calculate that, it will be obvious why $Y(\omega)$ only has support in those regions.